# Asp .Net web service in Sql Server 2008

Tags: android, asp.net, database, web-services, sql-server-2008

I parsed data from Asp .net web services in sql server 2008 and I can't take data When I increase number of request, Server doesn't work but after 1 hours server works and I can take data What is the problem Please Help me Web service configuration code is below

```
<configuration>`
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.3;initial catalog=DBAnket_Test;uid=sa;pwd=Spin123456;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your question properly but i think you need to check connection limits to SQL Server and to web service.

Comment: Actually my problem is I am making android application and I parse data from services I can take data from services When I request four times but more than request four times service doesn't work and I can't take data from it After one hours Services working itself and I can take data. What are you think about it?

Comment: I think you need to check connections limits to your web service.

Comment: My friend Which one need to check server side or web server side

Comment: First check in IIS.Select your website then click Advanced Settings and see Connection Limits Option there.Then you need to check how many simultaneous connections are allowed to SQL Server

Comment: it allows Maximum Concurrent Connection:4294967295 and Connection Timeout:120 second do I have to replace them

Comment: No its fine.Add this in your connection string and then check if it works Max Pool Size=200;

Comment: I don't understand Where do I add 4294967295,What is the pool Size I don't find it in sql server 2008

Comment: Max Pool Size=200; add this in your connection string in web.config your connection will be like this now     <add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.3;initial catalog=DBAnket_Test;uid=sa;pwd=Spin123456;Max Pool Size=200;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: it works..My friend thank you so much, but I can't understand what is pool size doing? is it expands limit of data transfer?

Comment: No it doesn't increase data transfer it allows number of connections in a pool which you set in connection string.A pool is created for the connection string in your case 200 connections are allowed. More information on this can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx